# How to vertically center a div within a div that changes height based on window size

Tags: html, css, center

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJyNQK)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="slogan">
        <div class="brand">
          <p>Contact us now!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
body {
  background-image:url(http://science-all.com/images/landscape/landscape-05.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%!important;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.wrapper {
  height:100%;
}

.logo {
  height:250px;
  background-color:aqua;
}

.slogan {
  min-height:200px;
  background-color:transparent;
}

.brand {
  color:aqua;
  font-size:25px;
  text-align:center;
}

</style>
```

I'd like the slogan div to adjust height based on the window size (eg to have the logo & slogan div fit the whole screen when the page is open). but keep the logo div a fixed size. The issue I am having now is centering the brand text vertically based on the div's size.

Answer (score 1):

You can display your `.slogan` div as `flexbox`.

```
.slogan {
  display: flex; /* Makes your slogan div flexbox */
  justify-content: center; /* Center the content of that div horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* Center the content of that div vertically */
  min-height:200px;
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqgpZr).

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box, which is probably the best solution, or if you don't want to do that you can use the CSS centering hack:

```
.slogan {
  position: relative;
}

.brand {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  (use vendor prefixes as well)
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You need set .slogan into position: relative.
2. You only change .brand to position: absolute and set position for it.

```css
body {
background-image:url(http://science-all.com/images/landscape/landscape-05.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
width: 100%!important;#
  padding:0;
  margin:0;}

.wrapper {
  height:100%;
}

.logo {
  height:250px;
  background-color:aqua;
}

.slogan {
  min-height:200px;
  position: relative;
}

.brand {
  color:aqua;
  font-size:25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="slogan">
  <div class="brand">
  <p> Contact us now!</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I sure it always vertically  of .slogan when responsive